# URL rewrite problems

Tags: php, jquery, url-rewriting

I wanted to pass the parameters to my PHP page in a friendly fashion, so here's what I wrote in .htaccess file

```
 RewriteRule ^confirm\/(([a-z0-9]).+)\/(([a-z0-9]).+)$ www.example.com/confirm.php?email=$1&order=$2
```

its working well, and I can get the parameters in PHP using

```
explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

I have 2 problems though,

1- when I submit this page, I need it to go directly to confirmation.php, instead it submits to www.example.com/confirm/example@mail.com/12-HDYF/confirmaction.php !!! how can this be changed.

2- the page was originally working perfectly, but when I type the friendly URL all jquery files give me the below error, which really seems unrelated.

[image]

Comment: 1) Show us how you submit the page. 2) Sounds like a 404 to me

Comment: The page contains a form, the form action="confirmation.php", it worked fine before url rewriting

Comment: Don't make it a relative path (`confirmation.php`).  Make it absolute like `/confirmation.php`, if that works.  Same with the paths to the JS files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the client (the browser) sees the page it is browsing as `www.example.com/confirm/example@mail.com/12-HDYF/` and when it analyzes it and parses the html, it sees it something like:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<form action="confirmation.php"... >
```

So the browser sees relative urls to the page he is at the moment. So if you tell him to search the `jquery.js` file in the same folder as the one he currently is, he is going to try to download from `www.example.com/confirm/example@mail.com/12-HDYF/jquery.js`, and the same thing happens when you submit the form.

To avoid this, use absolute URLs (note the leading slash):

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<form action="/confirmation.php"... >
```

If you have your files in a subfolder of the `DocumentRoot`, put that subfolder at the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change your url structure to avoid ^confirm for both raw and friendly URL, that should make things easier to debug (and avoid loops). This is a guess since you haven't posted your input that fails.

```
RewriteRule ^orderconf\/(([a-z0-9]).+)\/(([a-z0-9]).+)$ www.example.com/confirm.php?email=$1&order=$2
```

Comment: Also your original rewrite rule redirectsto confirm.php, but your recent comment states confirmation.php, which one is correct ?

Comment: the rewrite rule redirects to confirm.php, but when I submit, I need to submit to confirmation.php